# AndroidStudio: when I try to initialize a JSONObject in Unit test class it always outputs null

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, junit

I am trying to create a unit test for a class that uses json object.

This is the class I

```
    public JsonDataModel(String name, String tag, String color, double price) throws JSONException {
            this.name = name;
            this.tag = tag;
            this.color = color;
            this.price = price;
            initializeObject();
        }

  

     private void initializeObject() throws JSONException {
            object.put("Name", name);
            object.put("Tag", tag);
            object.put("Color", color);
            object.put("Price", price);
        }
```

This is the unit test setup:

```
    private JsonDataModel model;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws JSONException {
        
        model = new JsonDataModel("testName", "testTag", "testColor", 10);

    }
```

Once I run the test and `setUp()` is done, I checked the `object` inside `model` and it shows `null`. The weird thing is that if I try to run the app and look with the debugger at the objects created in `JsonDataModel`, the json object is generated correctly. It looks like when I try to initialize a `JSONObject` in the unit file test, it always outputs `null`. Does anyone have any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with the initializeObject function, it saves some data inside "object", but that "object" came from no where.
I don't see it anywhere inside the constructor, as if he's null when he reaches back to the Unit Test.

try to initialize this object before "putting" things inside it.

Comment: actually, the object is initialized, I just forgot to put it in the post, my bad. The object is initialized properly if I run the app, but not when I run the unit test. To be more specific, the problem is that I cannot create a proper unit test for the class that uses json objects, as the json objects are initialized as null in the unit test file. Even if I try to put in the constructor something basic like `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();` , obj would still be null.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the problem is that the line `testImplementation 'org.json:json:20140107'` is missing in `build.gradle(app)` in the `dependencies`